# What can I do to get rid of this syntax error on using namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I know everyone is going to say to not use namespace on everything but I don't know what I would need to do to get rid of it.

I'm trying to create a simple program that has three items that are part of a class and take user inputs for two of the functions.

header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class retailItem {
private:
    string description;
    int unitsOnHand;
    double price;
public:
    retailItem();
    retailItem(string, int, double);
    ~retailItem();
    void setDescription(string);
    string getDescription();
    void setUnitsOnHand(int);
    int getUnitsOnHand();
    void setPrice(double);
    double getPrice();
}
```

implementation.cpp:

```
#include "items.h"
using namespace std;

retailItem::retailItem() {
    description = "Small Tent";
    unitsOnHand = 200;
    price = 35.99;
}
retailItem::retailItem(string d, int u, double p) {
    description = d;
    unitsOnHand = u;
    price = p;
}
retailItem::~retailItem() {}
void retailItem::setDescription(string d) {
    description = d;
}
string retailItem::getDescription() {
    return description;
}
void retailItem::setUnitsOnHand(int u) {
    unitsOnHand = u;
}
int retailItem::getUnitsOnHand() {
    return unitsOnHand;
}
void retailItem::setPrice(double p) {
    price = p;
}
double retailItem::getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

main:

```
#include "items.h"
using namespace std;

void PrintItem(retailItem);
int TotalAmount(retailItem, retailItem, retailItem);
double TotalCost(retailItem, retailItem, retailItem);

int main() {
    string d;
    int u;
    double p;
    retailItem r1("Small Tent", 200, 35.99);
    retailItem r2;
    retailItem r3;

    cout << "Welcome to the tent store!\n\n";
    cout << "=====================\n\n";
    cout << "Enter description for item two: \n";
    getline(cin, d);
    cout << "Enter amount on hand for " << d << endl;
    cin >> u;
    if (u < 0)
        cout << "Amount must be greater than 0 \n";
    else;
    cout << "Enter price for " << d << endl;
    cin >> p;
    if (p < 0)
        cout << "Price must be greater than 0 \n";
    else;
    r2.setDescription(d);
    r2.setUnitsOnHand(u);
    r2.setPrice(p);
    cout << "Enter description for item three: \n";
    getline(cin, d);
    cout << "Enter amount on hand for " << d << endl;
    cin >> u;
    if (u < 0)
        cout << "Amount must be greater than 0 \n";
    else;
    cout << "Enter price for " << d << endl;
    cin >> p;
    if (p < 0)
        cout << "Price must be greater than 0 \n";
    else;
    r2.setDescription(d);
    r2.setUnitsOnHand(u);
    r2.setPrice(p);
    PrintItem(r1);
    PrintItem(r1);
    PrintItem(r1);
    cout << "\n The total amount on hand is: " << TotalAmount(r1, r2, r3) << endl;
    cout << "\n The total price of all items is: " << TotalCost(r1, r2, r3) << endl;
    }
void PrintItem(retailItem r) {
    cout << "\n Item Description: " << r.getDescription();
    cout << "\n Amount on hand: " << r.getUnitsOnHand();
    cout << "\n Item Description: " << r.getPrice();
}
int TotalAmount(retailItem r1, retailItem r2, retailItem r3) {
    return r1.getUnitsOnHand() + r2.getUnitsOnHand() + r3.getUnitsOnHand();
}
double TotalCost(retailItem r1, retailItem r2, retailItem r3) {
    return r1.getPrice() + r2.getPrice() + r3.getPrice();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEP0u.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class retailItem {

    // ... class declaration
}
```

Your class declaration is missing the trailing semicolon, here.

```
#include "items.h"
using namespace std;
```

An `#include` statement is equivalent to directly inserting the contents of the included file into the including file, ***verbatim***. So, you are asking the compiler to, effectively, compile something like this:

```
class retailItem {

// ... your class declaration.

} using namespace std;
```

This, of course, is gobbledygook, hence the compilation error. Just add a trailing semicolon:

```
class retailItem {

    // ... class declaration
};
```

Comment: That worked. Now I can clean it up and fix the other things that have now come up.